# Visual Studio 2012 designer screen gone black

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I have been developing a Windows Store App on Visual Studio 2012, few days back, I installed Update 3, following is my IDE information

*Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709
Installed Version: Professional*

But now, **the designer screen has turned black**, i can select the elements, but its all black. Check the image below:

[image: Visual Studio 2012 Designer problem]

I've tried repairing. Any idea whats wrong with it?

Comment: Well, it is not "all black".  Have you been playing with color themes?

Comment: ive just used the default feature of visual studio 2012, for themes.. nothing else

Comment: I have even tried resetting visual studio settings